# Django urls - don't allow direct opening when using {% include %}

Tags: python, django, datatables

In django 2.0.2 template I include datatable (from https://datatables.net/)

using

```
{% include 'ExchangesList.html' %}
```

in home.html

Everything is working fine.

But when I open /exchanges/exchanges_list_json/ in browser there is data used for table visible.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
#url(r'^$', ExchangesList.as_view(), name="exchanges"),
url(r'^exchanges_list_json/$', ExchangesListJson.as_view(), name="exchanges_list_json"),]
```

exchanges_list.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#exchanges_table').DataTable( {
       "ajax": EXCHANGES_LIST_JSON_URL,
...
```

home.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
var EXCHANGES_LIST_JSON_URL = '{% url "exchanges_list_json" %}';
</script>
...
```

views.py

```
class ExchangesList(TemplateView):
template_name = 'ExchangesList.html'

class ExchangesListJson(BaseDatatableView): 
    model = Exchanges
    columns = [
        'exchange_sort_id',
        'exchange_name',
        'exchange_country',
        'exchange_url',
        'exchange_trade_volume_24h_btc',
        'exchange_last_updated',
        ]
    order_columns = columns

def filter_queryset(self, qs):
    qs = Exchanges.objects.all()

    sSearch = self.request.GET.get('sSearch', None)
    if sSearch:
        qs = qs.filter(Q(exchange_name__istartswith=sSearch) | Q(exchange_description__istartswith=sSearch) | Q(exchange_id__istartswith=sSearch))
    return qs

def prepare_results(self, qs):
    qs = Exchanges.objects.all()

    json_data = []
    for item in qs:                
        json_data.append({
            'exchange_sort_id': escape(item.exchange_sort_id),
            'exchange_name': escape(item.exchange_name),  # escape HTML for security reasons
            'exchange_country': escape(item.exchange_country),
            'exchange_url': escape(item.exchange_url),
            'exchange_trade_volume_24h_btc': escape(item.exchange_trade_volume_24h_btc),
            'exchange_last_updated': item.exchange_last_updated.strftime("%H:%M:%S "),

        })

    #print(json_data)
    #print('len qs ' , len(qs))
    return json_data
```

How can I block direct opening exchanges_list_json.html keeping possibility to include?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with include. Or, for that matter, why you care that the data is visible.

Comment: To use include I need url right? so I can't remove url from urls.py. I want to google bot to index included content, but i don't want to show direct link in google search results.

Comment: No, include has nothing at all to do with URLs. It just includes a sub template inside the current one. You need a URL here because your datatable is losing its data dynamically via Ajax.

Comment: Ok. Have you any idea how can I get data without url?

Comment: You need the url. But if you don't want someone to be able to access it by typing in the url, you have to add the is_ajax() to the view. Then if it isn't an Ajax request, return a 404

Comment: how to add is_ajax() to  ExchangesListJson.as_view()?